# ¿Cómo se dice «side of beef» en español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, comida

Si buscas "side of beef," puedes ver que se trata de la mitad de la canal del animal, un producto comerciado al nivel mayorista.

No puedo encontrar el termino español. Una busca para "lado de carne" produce resultas con imágenes no iguales.

¿Cuál seria el termino correcto?

Comment: Quizás *canal* -- "Res muerta y abierta, sin las tripas y demás despojos."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of "side of beef" [seems](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clasificaci%C3%B3n_de_la_carne) to be *carne en canal*, or in shortened form, *canal* (female), but I'm not sure if this refers to the actual piece of the animal or to the mode of cutting. In Argentina, Uruguay, Paraguay and very possibly other countries in South America, the name for this in common parlance and in the industry is *media res*, i.e. literally "half a cow".

*[Res](https://dle.rae.es/res?m=form)* is a specialized word, used practically only in the context of livestock farming and processing; it's [a general term for farm animals](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=res). (Not to be confused with the Latin expression *[in medias res](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_medias_res)*.)

Comment: Me parece bien esta respuesta.  Hay un libro que usa los dos términos: "Sistemas de tipificación de canales bovinas."

Comment: How about «media canal?»